# How to hide/exclude a product for the list of products

Tags: 6, ubercart

I want to hide or exclude a product listed in the list of products displayed by Ubecart (for example in the catalog list, or list of nodes displayed by a taxonomy term). That I want is just allowing the users to visit the product directly (from a email for example).

Comment: Hello. Answers for catalog module may differ greatly from answers for taxonomy terms, and then you have views you can use to list products too. And you didn't mentioned what products you want to hide, how would you recognize them. Is replacing all listings with views an option?